# Complex mongodb query with Quarkus

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I need to migrate a Spring Boot project to Quarkus. The project has been using Spring Data Mongodb for all the queries. Now I find it difficult to migrate complex queries.

One example is

```
public List<MyData> findInProgressData(MyConditions conditions) {
    Query mongoQuery = new Query();

    mongoQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("status").is(IN_PROGRESS));
    mongoQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("location").is(conditions.getLocationCode()));

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(conditions.getType())) {
        mongoQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("type").is(conditions.getType()));
    }

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(conditions.getUserId())) {
        mongoQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("userId").is(conditions.getUserId()));
    }

    mongoQuery.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "createdAt"));

    return mongoTemplate.find(mongoQuery, MyData.class);
}
```

How can I implement the conditional query with Quarkus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably try [Panache with Mongodb](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache). 
You can pass `Document` into `.find()` method, In this object you can specify any criteria.

```
        final Document document = new Document();
        document.put("status","IN_PROGRESS");
        ...
        result = MyData.find(document); // or MyDataRepository
```

But you'll need to adapt some of the code to Panache, which can be done either via extending `PanacheEntity` or `PanacheEntityBase`